# Error "Invalid crypto padding" using jwt from RoR to Flask

Tags: python, flask, jwt

I have a singular case. For different reasons, I need to use a JWT generated by an app in Ruby on Rails, in a Flask app, with [Flask-JWT-Extended](https://flask-jwt-extended.readthedocs.io/).

**- EDIT:**

Now I know, the token is generated by Devise library (it's true?) in a magic `sign_in` method (*IDK* anything about Ruby and RoR, sorry).

This magic (for me) method generates a token like this:

```
eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJ1c2VyX2lkIjo2MSwiZXhwIjoxNTg3MjIyMjQ5fQ.KcqNDwNjkTPD6rKgTMrt2lw9Swso6gRvLhPq-QvfA6Q}
```

In Python I have a normal configuration for Flask-JWT-Extended. In Config I have:

```py
class Config(object):
    JWT_AUTH_USERNAME_KEY = 'user_id'
    JWT_AUTH_HEADER_PREFIX = 'Bearer'
    SECRET_KEY = os.getenv('SECRET_KEY')
    JWT_IDENTITY_CLAIM = 'user_id'
```

But, when I use the "magic" token for call to the app in Flask, this returns the error:

```
{
    "msg": "Invalid crypto padding"
}
```

I have the same secret key in both apps.

I don't know much about Ruby, and I don't know what happens.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why, but if I remove the last character `}` the token works in Pyhton too...

Comment: same thing with me, after removing the last character the token is working fine